# CORS error when connecting AWS React app to a Node.js API on AWS

Tags: reactjs, node.js, amazon-web-services, cors, pm2

I'm encountering CORS (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing) errors in my web application, and I'm seeking help to troubleshoot and resolve this issue. Here are the key details of my setup:

- Front-End: My web application uses React version 16.14.
- Back-End: The API is built using Node.js version 16.19 with
  Express.js version 4.18.1.
- Server Instance: Both the React front-end and Node.js API are hosted
  on a single AWS EC2 instance (t3.large).
- Database: The application relies on a MySQL database hosted on AWS
  RDS.
- Process Management: I use PM2 to manage services for both the React
  front-end and Node.js API.
- Load Balancer: My setup includes an AWS Application Load Balancer.
- Auto Scaling: I've configured an auto scaling group, so when the CPU
  utilization of the instance exceeds 35%, a new instance is
  automatically spun up to handle the load.

The issue I'm facing is that during specific peak traffic times, particularly at 9:30 AM, CORS errors occur. The rest of the time, the application runs smoothly without any problems.

I suspect that the CORS errors may be related to how my load balancer, auto scaling, or perhaps CORS settings are configured. I'm looking for guidance on how to:

- Diagnose the CORS error during high traffic periods, particularly
  when the server is under load.
- Understand the interplay between the AWS Application Load Balancer,
  auto scaling, and CORS.
- Configure CORS settings to avoid these errors during peak traffic
  times.

I would appreciate any insights, tips, or advice on how to resolve this CORS issue and ensure a consistently smooth user experience, especially during high traffic periods.

Thank you in advance for your help!

- CORS Configuration: I initially reviewed and adjusted the CORS
  configuration on the server-side (Node.js API) to accept requests
  from the domain of my React front-end. This included setting
  appropriate headers in the response.
- Preflight Requests: I ensured that the API handles preflight requests
  (OPTIONS) correctly, and the responses include the necessary CORS
  headers.
- AWS Load Balancer: I checked the AWS Application Load Balancer
  settings to ensure that it's correctly forwarding requests to my EC2
  instance.
- Load Testing: I performed load testing on my application to replicate
  the high traffic scenario. This helped me identify that the CORS
  errors tend to occur during specific peak hours.

My expectation was that after configuring the CORS settings and ensuring proper handling of preflight requests, the CORS errors would not occur, even during high traffic times. I expected the AWS Application Load Balancer and auto scaling group to efficiently distribute traffic and handle the load without causing CORS issues.

However, despite these efforts, I'm still encountering CORS errors during peak traffic times, especially at 9:30 AM. I'm seeking guidance on potential configurations or adjustments I might be overlooking or any best practices for handling CORS in such a setup.

Header settings:

```
const origin = req.headers.origin;
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', origin);
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,content-type,accept,authorization');
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Max-Age', '240');
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
```

[CORS error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GORFl.png)

[CORS error request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PIb54.png)

[CORS error response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GGNgO.png)

Comment: What does the CORS error look like?

Comment: Is the auto-scaling group actually adding nodes to the group when this happens? You may have the load balancer configured such that it starts sending traffic to new nodes before those nodes are truly ready to handle the traffic. You really need to identify what is actually happening on AWS when these issues occur. You also need to find the actual HTTP response to the failed CORS requests (is it a CORS denial, or more likely some sort of HTTP error response) and add those **specific** details to your question.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: i have added screenshot and code to better understand.

Comment: These screenshots are not helpful. Please paste all the relevant information (CORS requests, including preflight; response codes; console errors if any) as text. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you have not implemented [health checks](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/target-group-health-checks.html) in your Express.js app and registered them with the load balancer, the freshly started instance can start receiving traffic before it's ready to handle it.

Comment: I have actually tried it without auto scaling too. Without Auto Scaling, when the CPU utilization reaches about 40%, it starts showing CORS error in browser.